Why is there a high correlation even if scatterplot does not show it?
I can not understand why correlation coefficient is very high (r=0.9244), even if there is no linear relationship in the structure of scatterplot.

I calculated it using matlab:
r = corrcoef(x, y);

How can I interpret this ?

it seems like you have a point at the origin (blue circle there). How many such points are there?

Yes you were right... there were data points at zero.

Besides the points at zero, the axis ranges are different. If you use the same range for the y axis than that of the X axis you will probably see the correlation much more clearly

There is possibility that your data has too many outliers. Check for possible outliers in your data also if you think it is suitable for your data possibly try Spearman's Correlation method.
If after removing outliers and change of correlation method you get same high coefficient, you probably have some problem with data.

Why do outliers increase linear correlation coefficient?

Ok I understand. There were a lot of points at zero.
